# How to fix charset of csv file in Blob correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have `.csv` file which has some not latin letters. Other word, the file contains сyrillic letters. I use next code to download that `.csv` file by browser. The problem is that instead of normal letters I see such symbols `???` in downloaded file. I need convert `response.data` to `windows-1251` charset. How I can make it correctly?

```
axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/static/daily.csv',
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob',
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data)
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`iconv-lite`](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) with [Browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify):

```
const buf = iconv.encode(response.data, 'win1251');
```